# scp or rsync multiple files from source server to another servers

Tags: shell-script, rsync, nfs, scp

Since my `nfs` is a `win` type of server, it can't contain `:`. I want to copy multiple files from source server to the `nfs` directory on another server and rename them at the same time.

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

in_files="node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*"
###########################################################
# the files look like wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_06:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_12:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_18:00:00
###################################
for fn in $in_files;do
  echo $fn
  newfn=$(basename "$fn")
  echo 'apply basename :'
  echo $newfn
  scp -r "$fn"  "./${newfn//:/_}"
  echo 'next:'
done
```

After run this script, it reports

```
node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*
apply basename :
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_12_00_00
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
next:
```

But it seems that if I apply the script to only one file, it is OK,(i.e. change the `in_files` to a certain file),for example:

```
node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
apply basename :
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00        100%   71MB  70.5MB/s   00:00    
next:
```

1.So how should I do to let it work for multiple files?

2.By the way it seems `rsync` can also do this part, which one is faster or preferred.

Comment: There are also [other characters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) that a Windows-based NFS server can't accept. It might be easier to fix up the names in your source tree.

Comment: Also move the glob outside the quotes `in_files=("node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01"*)` and `for fn in "${in_files[@]}"; do`

Comment: @Inian, it didn't work.

Comment: @AllenZhang saying "_it didn't work_" gives no assistance to the person trying to help you. What happened? What didn't happen? What error messages or other output did you get?